# Dicas para fazer um codigo mais limpo

Tags: java, revisão-de-código

To iniciando em programação em java e gostaria de saber como fazer códigos mais limpo, esse é um exemplo de um codigo recente que criei

````
public void chamarButton(JTextField login, JTextField senha){

        String pass = "";
        Connection connection = Connectionfactory.getConnection();
        try{
            String sqlLogin = "select senha from administrador where login = " + "'"+login.getText()+"'";
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSetlogin = statement.executeQuery(sqlLogin);
            while(resultSetlogin.next()){
               pass = resultSetlogin.getString(1);
                System.out.println(resultSetlogin.getString(1));
            }
             if (pass.equals(senha.getText())){
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"SUCESSO");
                 this.ativo = true;
             }else if(pass == "")
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"Login errado");
             else
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "senha errada");
                  resultSetlogin.close();
        }catch (SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"ERRO AO LOGAR");
            e.printStackTrace();```

Como deixar ele mais limpo por exemplo
````

Comment: Para comparar strings se usa `equals` em vez de `==`, então seria `if ("".equals(pass))`

Answer (score 0):

1. Seu método recebe JTextFields, que são componentes de GUI, e faz uma consulta no banco. Ah, e fazer autenticação de login e senha. Ah! E avisa com componente gráfico se der erro. Não tem nada a ver uma coisa com a outra. Sugiro fazer uma coisa só de cada vez (não é regra, que dizer alguns dizem que é, mas o ponto é que quanto menos coisa faz mais limpo fica): por exemplo receber strings (é melhor nesse caso porque são mais genéricas que JTextFields), consultar o banco, e do lado de fora do método (ou em em outro objeto) autenticar e avisar se der erro.
2. Estude sobre SQL injection e a diferença entre Statement e PreparedStatement.
3. Estude sobre try-with-resources.